# How to tackle when one parameter depends on the other in RSTAN

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

I have a Stan code in which the one of the model parameters depends on another parameter. In total I have 5 parameters: **mu, alpha,beta, gamma, delta**. Now beta depends on alpha in a way that-

```
beta> 1- (alpha/1.17)
```

.The parameter block currently looks like:

```
parameters{
real<lower=0> mu;
real<lower=0,upper=1.17> alpha;
real beta;
real<lower=1> gamma;
real<lower=0> delta;
}
```

How can I put the lower bound of beta inside the parameter block?

The code is :

```
expcode="
    functions{
real loglikelihood(int N,
real mu,
real alpha,
real beta,
real gamma,
real delta,
real[] t,
real[] m,
real[] rts,
real magmin,
real tmax,
real betalim){

  real tempA;
  real sumtermA;
  real a;
  real tempB;
  real final;

  sumtermA=log(mu);
  for(j in 2:N){
   tempA=mu;
   for(i in 1:(j-1)){
    tempA += beta*(exp(alpha*(m[i]-magmin)))*(gamma - 1) * delta^(gamma- 1) *(1 / (t[j]-t[I]+delta)^gamma);
   }
   sumtermA += log(tempA);
  }
  tempB=0;
  for(j in 1:N){
   tempB += beta*(exp(alpha*(m[j]-magmin)))*(1-((delta^(gamma- 1))/((tmax-t[j]+delta)^(gamma-1))));
}

 a= mu*tmax;
 final= sumtermA-a-tempB+sum(rts);
 return(final);

  }
}
      data{
        int<lower=0> N;
        real<lower=0> t[N];
        real<lower=0> m[N];
        real rts[N];
        real<lower=0> tmax;
        real<lower=0> magmin;
        real<lower=0> betalim;
        }
       parameters{
     real<lower=0> mu;
     real<lower=0,upper=betalim> alpha;
     real<lower=0> beta;
     real<lower=1> gamma;
     real<lower=0> delta;
     }
     model{
      mu~normal(1.5,1.5);
      alpha~normal(0,0.1);
      beta~normal(0,0.1);
      gamma~normal(1.12,0.16);
      delta~gamma(0.1,0.1);

       //likelihood
          target+=    (loglikelihood(N,mu,alpha,beta,gamma,delta,t,m,rts,magmin,tmax,betalim));
        }
   "

   data<-   list(N=300,t=runif(300,0,1),m=runif(300,2,9),rts=runif(300,-3,3),tmax=1,magmin=2,betalim=1.17)
```

Comment: *"How can I put the lower bound of beta inside the parameter block?"* What do you mean? You have already declared `beta` (as a lower-bounded `real`) in the `parameter` block.

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, but it should be greater than 1- (alpha/1.17). how can I do that?

Comment: @MauritsEvers just did a little edit. did not put any lower bound right now. But beta should be greater than 1- (alpha/1.17). Is it possible to put this kind of constraints inside the parameter block of rstan?

Comment: But you define `beta = 1 - alpha / 1.17`, so I don't understand what you mean by *"`beta` should be greater than 1-(alpha/1.17)"*. `beta` *is* `1 - alpha / 1.17`.

Comment: OK. Now I understand! Sorry, I mistook the `>` sign above for a corrupted `->`. Can you please provide a minimal example including sample data (something similar to what I did below) plus stan model for estimating `alpha` and `beta`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have written in my question that beta> 1- (alpha/1.17), not beta=1- (alpha/1.17)

Comment: Yes, I realised that; see my previous comment!

Comment: @MauritsEvers okay. please wait. it's a long code

Comment: @MauritsEvers please see the code in the original question and the data

Comment: Please take a look at my revised/expanded answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tldr;

You can realise parameter constraints that are based on other parameters through the `lower`/`upper` bounds.

---

### A simple example

Let's create a simple example by fitting a normal distribution to some random data to estimate the normal's parameters `mu` (mean) and `sigma` (stdev), as well as a transformed parameter `nu = 1/sigma`. We impose the constraint `nu > 1 / sigma - 1`.

1. First, let's define our model. For simplicity, I'll use flat (i.e. default) priors.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int N;                                       // Number of observations
       real y[N];                                   // Response
   }

   parameters {
       real mu;                                     // Model parameters
       real<lower=1e-5> sigma;                      // Standard deviation
   }

   transformed parameters {
       real<lower = 1 / sigma - 1, upper = positive_infinity()> nu;
       nu = 1 / sigma;
   }

   model {
       y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
   }
   "
   ```

   We define and declare the transformed parameter `nu` in block `transformed parameters`. Additionally we impose the constraint `nu > 1 / sigma - 1` through the lower/upper bounds `<lower=1/sigma-1, upper=positive_infinity()>`.
2. Let's generate some sample data. Here we choose `mu = 2` and `nu = 1/sigma = 4`.

   ```
   set.seed(2017);
   mu <- 2;
   nu <- 4;
   y <- rnorm(100, mean = mu, sd = 1/nu);
   ```
3. Let's fit the model.

   ```
   library(rstan);
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
   fit <- stan(model_code = model, data = list(N = length(y), y = y));
   fit;
   #Inference for Stan model: 16495e5aad9d987998077084a6630917.
   #4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1;
   #post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.
   #
   #       mean se_mean   sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
   #mu     2.00    0.00 0.03  1.95  1.98  2.00  2.02  2.06  3382    1
   #sigma  0.27    0.00 0.02  0.24  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.31  3114    1
   #nu     3.72    0.00 0.26  3.21  3.54  3.71  3.89  4.25  3128    1
   #lp__  80.24    0.02 0.96 77.66 79.84 80.54 80.93 81.19  1719    1
   #
   #Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Mon Jun 25 11:01:06 2018.
   #For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
   #and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split chains (at
   #convergence, Rhat=1).
   ```

   You can see that the estimates for `mu` and `nu` are in excellent agreement with our chosen parameter values, and that indeed `nu > 1 / sigma - 1`.

---

### Your case

You should be able to impose the constraint  `beta > 1 - alpha / 1.17` by declaring `beta` as

```
...
real<lower=0,upper=betalim> alpha;
real<lower = 1 - alpha / 1.17, upper = positive_infinity()> beta;
...
```

Comment: thanks for the example. But nu is here = 1/sigma. In my case, beta should be greater than (1-alpha/1.17). how to do this?

Comment: @forstack Please see my comment to your original post above.

Comment: The `upper = positive_infinity()>` can be omitted but is not wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BenGoodrich.

Comment: @forstack BTW, my 2012 MacBook Air struggles to fit your model; a single chain is taking around 2 hours, so I haven't done any testing on your actual model+data.

Comment: @MauritsEvers is it taking long time as because you are taking an improper prior?

Comment: @forstack I've tried running the model plus sample data that you provided, which uses normal (fairly informative) priors on all parameters. I don't have enough information to understand *what* your model describes, so my plan was to quickly (and unsuccessfully) compare results with/without including the `lower` bound on `beta`. Either way, you can include a condition of one parameter on another in the way I demonstrate, which should answer your original question.

Comment: @MauritsEvers okay. that you very much. I accepted your answer but since my reputation is too low, probably you won't get the notification. Thanks for making the answer clear

Comment: No worries & you're very welcome @forstack; BTW, you can close the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer, which works at all reputation levels (upvoting on the other hand requires at least 15 rep). Good luck with your work.